# Sony Xperia Date Issue

Tags: android, jodatime

I came across the most weird problem with dates on a Sony Xperia LT26i. A date format: "hh:mm:ss a" will print "01:00 p.m." and on most devices it prints "01:00 pm". Any clue why is this? It is messing my joda time as I cant parse times that come from the server.

Answer (score 0):

JodaTime can parse the local am/pm-strings your device produces. What to do with different strings coming from server? Since you expect fortunately only the markers "am" or "pm" from server I suggest to use two specialized formatter objects using am/pm-literals for parsing. So that is the workaround:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter AM_PARSER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss 'am'");
static final DateTimeFormatter PM_PARSER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss 'pm'");

public static LocalTime parseServer(String input) {
  if (input.endsWith("am")) {
    return AM_PARSER.parseLocalTime(input);
  } else {
    LocalTime lt = PM_PARSER.parseLocalTime(input);
    return lt.plusHours(12); // necessary because we parse pm only as literal
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

If you study the [JodaTime-source code](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/chrono/GJLocaleSymbols.java) then you will find that am/pm-strings finally come from `DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale).getAmPmStrings()`. So the question arises why you have "p.m." instead of "pm" on Sony Xperia device. This leads to the question what is the data source of class `DateFormatSymbols`. This is dependent on the JVM-provider who manages such data in any resource directory (in your case dependent on your special Android configuration, in my case in resource bundle class `sun.text.resources.FormatData`). It is really different for every JVM (and Android is not even an official Java-VM).

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a little bit I have come up with this solution

```
public static LocalTime localTimeParse(String date, DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter)       {

    if(!StringUtils.hasText(date) || dateTimeFormatter == null)
        return null;

    LocalTime localTime = null;

    try {
        localTime = LocalTime.parse(date,dateTimeFormatter);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        //This can happen on devices that have their time in the following format "01:00 p.m." insetad of "01:00 pm" 
        //Sony Xperia lT26i is one of them

        String newDate = date.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains("am") ? date.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).replace("am", "a.m.") : date.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).replace("pm", "p.m.");
        localTime = LocalTime.parse(newDate,dateTimeFormatter);
    }

    return localTime;
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime localTime = DateUtils.localTimeParse("09:00 PM",formatter);
```

It works on Xperia a non Xperia